# Conidtional MySQL WHERE Statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, where-clause

I'm trying to write a MySQL Statement for and advanced search bar. Essentially I need it to only include sections of a WHERE statement, if a variable is not blank.

This is where I've given up:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE if($brand != '', brand='$brand' AND, brand LIKE _%)";
```

Something like this is what I need:

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE (brand = variable)<-[ONLY IF VARIABLE IS NOT BLANK]
```

I'm really trying to refrain from having a binary system with thousands of IF statements.

EDIT:

It's also worth nothing that I will need over 10 If-Statements within this WHERE

EDIT:

Also, the variable I'm checking to be blank is stored locally in the PHP not on the MySQL Server. To try to be more specific to what I'm looking for:

```
$brand = "Samsung";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE [IF BRAND != NULL USE THIS STRING FOR WHERE STATEMENT -> brand='$brand'] [SECOND IF] [THIRD IF]";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `PDO` or `MySQLi` but the below is just to give you an idea :

```
    $query = "
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Products
WHERE
    1";

    if( $brand != '' )
    {
        $query .= "
    AND brand = '" .$brand ."'";
    }

    if( $color != '' )
    {
        $query .= "
    AND color = '" .$color ."'";
    }
```

Comment: This works beautifully! Thanks! And I'm not worried about the security of it, because it will only be myself and few other managers at my company using this on a local network.

Comment: "not worried about the security of it" is a terrible thing to say. What if someone thinks this tool is so great they start sharing it with customers? Do it right the first time. No excuses.

Answer (score 0):

It's much more convenient if by "blank" you mean `NULL`:

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE brand IS NULL
```

If you're dealing with potentially blank strings, then it looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE brand IS NULL OR brand=''
```

It gets messy if you're dealing with things that might be "couple of spaces, maybe a tab or two randomly", so you might want to null-out any data in the application code that inserts this.

Comment: True, however that will search the MySQL database for NULL Brands. Whereas I need to check a variable in my PHP script for NULL and if it is not NULL than include this snippet in Query.